# How do I treat foreign words after its English counterpart?

Tags: foreign-phrases

I'm formatting a Bible study that includes Hebrew and Greek Words.

The PDFs of so many Bible studies were created long ago, and will be available as downloads on the site I'm **RE**building. I'm formatting the web text. I have a slight amount of leeway on correcting things.

Here are two examples:

> - "Notice that an overseer episkopos or pastor-teacher..."
> - "But an additional listed iniquity is the Hebrew word abomination toebah which is also..."

How should I treat this kind of thing? I plan to italicize the foreign word in any event. Should I enclose the foreign word in parentheses? Should I set it apart with commas or em dashes? The English word precedes the foreign word here, and the *Chicago Manual of Style* doesn't seem to address this situation.

Comment: Who is CMS? What do other sources do?

Comment: Content management system. You should write to Logos for advice.

Comment: There are too many issues not related to the English language to fulfill your task. e.g. UTF-8 vs code page. How to mix LTR with RTL languages on the same line. This question should not be asked here, but in a web layout/designing forum.

Comment: I agree with @BlessedGeek that you should probably take this to another forum, but what might help is to ask, __is the Greek/Hebrew _necessary_ to understanding the Bible study's message__? If it isn't, then I'd say skip it in the main text and use footnotes or separate glossary-like pages to give your students the extra information if they want it.

Comment: I edited this question to clarify that the poster was using _CMS_ as an initialism for _Chicago Manual of Style_.

Answer (score 1):

In print I’m comfortable with minimal differences

Notice that an overseer, 'επίσκκοπος, or pastor-teacher…
Notice that an overseer *episkopos* or 'pastor-teacher'...

but on screen I find it more helpful to have stronger emphasis, and more white space, especially if the page cannot easily be enlarged.

Notice that an overseer **episkopos** or *pastor-teacher*...
Notice that an overseer, **'επίσκκοπος**, or *'pastor-teacher'*

But this only works for the occasional word or half verse; it  will look clumsy if there are chunks of Greek /Latin /Hebrew text.

One journal (Notes & Queries) gives the following guidance (but using underline, where this is italicised). And this would meet your case I think.

> A word or phrase discussed individually should be underlined, and any
> interpretation of it put in single quotation marks. E.g.:
>
> For *Cain* 1261 (misread as *cam*) he writes *camp* `battle'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are following *Chicago* style, you'll be interested to know that *The Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003) addresses this very point in its subsection on "Square Brackets":

> **6.105** *In translations.* In a translated work, square brackets are sometimes used to enclose a word or phrase in the original language to avoid ambiguity. (Translators  should use this device sparingly.)
>
> > The difference between society [*Gesellschaft*] and community [*Gemeinde*] will now be analyzed.

Applying the explicit guideline here about square brackets and the implicit one about italicizing foreign words yields the following forms for your two examples:

> - "Notice that an overseer [*episkopos*] or pastor-teacher..."
> - "But an additional listed iniquity is the Hebrew word abomination [*toebah*] which is also..."

Answer (score 0):

My version of CMS (14) doesn't have 6.105 - I suppose I should upgrade. Good to know. We went ahead and used parentheses.